# Send event to underlying iframe

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have an iframe with video player and I want to disable some it's features. Since there is no documentation, I've just created a div, put it on top of the iframe and when I check coordinates of users clicks I decide whether I need to transmit this click to this iframe or not. Here's how it looks like:

```
<iframe
    src="http://website.com/embed/dfgdgssg"
    style="position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 350px;"></iframe>
<div id="hideme"></div>
<script>
$('iframe').load(function() {
        var iframe = $(this);
        var hideme = $('#hideme');

        hideme.width(iframe.width());
        hideme.height(iframe.height());
        hideme.css('left', iframe.position().left);
        hideme.css('top', iframe.position().top);

        hideme.on("click", function(event){
            iframe.trigger(event);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Using `console.log()` I can see that event `click` for `#hideme` is executed, but nothing changes for the iframe though.

Comment: What should change in the iframe?

Comment: `click` event should be executed in specific position to start playing.

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu, Still don't understand how to send event using that.